# JavaScript will not run at all

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra

I have this template as my sinatra `layout.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Invoicer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
       ...
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%#<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>%>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
    <script src="/static/js/jobs/new.js" />
</body>
</html>
```

and this small javascript call

```
console.log("running")
$('#datepicker').datepicker()
```

the server gets a 200 call to the js file but nothing will print to the console or execute.

Comment: Don't use two versions of jQuery.

Comment: Where am I doing that? the first one is commented out. The console.log does not even execute. the console is blank

Comment: Oops; I missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Always use `<script></script>`.

`<script src="..." />` is not a valid tag. When the HTML is parsed, it thinks that `<script src="/static/js/jobs/new.js" />` is in the *body* of the `<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"/>` tag like this:

```
...
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js">
  <script src="/static/js/jobs/new.js">
...
```

From [MDN `<script>` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> **Tag omission**
>
> None, both the starting and ending tag are mandatory.